# Converting Odd Date Format Into a Number

Tags: excel, vba, import

I have a VBA script that pulls in data from a page similar to this one:

http://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=12&day=30&year=2013

The problem is when it pastes the "MP" field into Excel, it comes in a weird format. For example, the first row shows Kevin Love with 39:42, but in Excel it shows as 15:42, and when I click on it, the value actually shows 1/1/1900  3:42:00 PM

I tried changing the format of the column that it imports to and reimporting, but it gives the same result.

Ideally I'd like it to come in as 39.66 (39 minutes and 40ish seconds) but if it just came in as text with the colon I could make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here's my current code, if it helps:

```
Sub DailyImport()
'
' DailyImport Macro
'

'
Dim day As Integer
Dim month As Integer
Dim year As Integer
Dim indexD As Integer
Dim indexM As Integer
Dim indexY As Integer

day = 1
month = 10
year = 2013
NextRow = 1

    For indexY = year To 2014
        For indexM = month To 12
            For indexD = day To 31
            Range("A" & NextRow).Select
            With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                "URL;http://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=" & month & "&day=" & day & "&year=" & year & "" _
                , Destination:=Range("$A" & NextRow))
                .Name = "dailyleaders.cgi?month=" & month & "&day=" & day & "&year=" & year & "_1"
                .FieldNames = False
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .BackgroundQuery = False
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = False
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
                .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
                .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
                .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = False
                .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
                .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
                .WebDisableRedirections = False
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

            End With
            day = day + 1
            FirstRow = NextRow
            NextRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Range("AD" & FirstRow + 1, "AD" & NextRow) = month & "/" & day - 1 & "/" & year
            Next indexD
            month = month + 1
            day = 1
        Next indexM
        year = year + 1
        month = 1
        day = 1
    Next indexY

End Sub
```

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: Just added my code Gary, hope that helps. And thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel handles time values in unfortunate ways. ":" separated numbers are HH:MM[:ss], even if you'd prefer MM:SS. And, changing the formatting of the column after the import is too late.
Thus, "39:42" is interpreted as 24 hours plus 15hours:42mins, which, in turn is interpreted as 3:42:00PM.
Which is what you are seeing.

Solutions:

1. If you have control over the CSV export, perhaps you can export the MP field as '39:42 (notice the opening apostrophe), which causes Excel to interpret this as a string, which you can later parse with a relevant function. By far, the easiest solution, since everyone will benefit.
2. If you save the CSV file, you can, during the Excel Open/Import, control the column format, Change it to Text.  Click the Data tab > Import from Text button, then walk through the import.
3. If you don't have control over the export, as a test, I used emacs to substitute ([0-9][0-9]:) with '\&. Now, I have '39:42.  (If you don't understand that, look up "regular expressions".) You can, of course, use something like Perl to just script the change if this is going to be a regular thing. Anyway, change your tables, and load the csv file as normal.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a csv export at all, I'm just going to the page and copy/pasting the table that is there. Do the same solutions apply in that case?

Answer (score 0):

## Code:

`Range.Formula = "=TIMEVALUE(""00:" & TimeValue & """)"`

This will keep the time as a value that you can use for calculations.